# Issue on Running Bootstrap Switch 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Can you please take a look at [This Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/2RzDd/1/) and let me know why I am not able to run the Bootstrap Switch 3 on this sample:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="well">
        <input type="checkbox" name="my-checkbox" checked />
    </div>         
</div>

<script>
$(function() {
  $("[name='my-checkbox']").bootstrapSwitch();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need the bootstrap switch js and css files surely! Here are the instructions - http://www.bootstrap-switch.org/

Here is an update of demo - http://jsfiddle.net/ctbZ9/

```
<script src="http://www.bootstrap-switch.org/dist/js/bootstrap-switch.js"></script>
```